# Add key/value pair to NewValues dictionary of RowUpdating event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `<asp:GridView>` that has some `<asp:BoundField>`s and a `<asp:TemplateField>`.

It also has event handelers for `RowEditing` and `RowUpdating` events.

The `<asp:TemplateField>` looks like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("active") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActive" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Yes" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="No" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The problem I'm having is that when `RowUpdating` event handeler is called there is no key/value pair for the `TemplateField` column in the `e.NewValues` dictionary.  I just see the key/value pairs for the `BoundField`s.

Is there something I'm forgeting to do in the `RowEditing` event handeler in order to add to the `NewValues` dictionary or do i need something else in my `EditItemTemplate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not forgetting anything but you should know that the `e.NewValues` retrieves the key/value of bound data in the gridview control only, and your drop-down-list it's not bound to your gridview but it is an external control.

So to get the drop-down-list's key/value data from your gridview you could use the code below:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlActive");
    string ddlKey = ddl.SelectedItem.Value;
    string ddlValue = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;

    // rest of your code here ...
}
```